# Hive CAST to BIGINT returns null

Tags: hive, hql

I need to convert it to biginteger as I need to XOR the same with another biginteger(123456789123) in my hive result.

`select cast("18072662652752953069" as bigint);`

returns `NULL`;

Am I missing something here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It returns `NULL` simply because you have supplied a number that is greater than the largest number that `bigint` can represent.

As per this [Language Manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-NumericTypes)

> BIGINT (8-byte signed integer, from -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to
>   9,223,372,036,854,775,807)

Comment: and if you haven't?